# A question about a proof from Ahlfors' book, complex analysis

Tags: complex-analysis

Here is a proof from Ahlfors' book (first edition) for the following theorem:

**Theorem 7: Suppose that $f(z)$ is analytic in the region $\Omega'$ obtained by omitting a point $a$ from a region $\Omega$. A necessary and sufficient condition that there exist an analytic function in $\Omega$ which coincides with $f(z)$ in $\Omega'$ is that $\lim_{z\to a}(z-a)f(z)=0$. The extended function is uniquely determined.**

**proof** (partial): To prove the sufficiency, we draw a circle $C$ about $a$ so that $C$ and its inside are contained in $\Omega$. Cauchy's formula is valid, and we can write
$$
f(z)=\frac{1}{2\pi i}\int_{C}\frac{f(w)}{w-z}dw
$$
for all $z\neq a$ inside of $C$. But the integral in the right-hand member represents an analytic function of $z$ throughout the inside of $C$. Consequently, the function which is equal to $f(z)$ for $z\neq a$ and which has the value
$$
\frac{1}{2\pi i}\int_{C}\frac{f(w)}{w-a}dw
$$
for $z=a$ is analytic in $\Omega$."

**My question**: Why Cauchy's formula is valid and why we can write
$$
f(z)=\frac{1}{2\pi i}\int_{C}\frac{f(w)}{w-z}dw\quad ?
$$
In order to use Cauchy's formula we need that $f(z)$ will be analytic in inside $C$ (Theorem 6). In this case $f$ may not be defined in $a$. Where he uses the assumption that $\lim_{z\to a}(z-a)f(z)=0$ ? I know that if $f$ in continuous on $C$, then the function
$$
\frac{1}{2\pi i}\int_{C}\frac{f(w)}{w-z}dw
$$
is analytic inside $C$ (Lemma 3), but why it coincides with $f(z)$?

**Note**: Although a related question was asked in
[Question about an extension of an analytic function](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/768110/question-about-an-extension-of-an-analytic-function), my question is different.

Comment: That's a weird spelling of "Ahlfors"

Comment: you apply Cauchy (the general formula for domains bounded by a few Jordan curves) to the annulus where you exclude a small circle of radius $\epsilon$ around $a$; the condition in the hypothesis implies that the integral on the small circle goes to zero as $\epsilon \to 0$